# Is there a way to disable error regarding "Cannot determine the module for component..."?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I've added a new component to my TypeScript2+Angular2+Ionic2 project. For now, **I don't want to add it reference it anywhere in my project yet**. I want to built it out completely first.  I can't be sure, but I think Angular/ngc is throwing an error saying "Cannot determine the module for component Main".

Is there way to disable this error.  In my mind, this should be a warning, and shouldn't stop me from (ahead of time) compiling.

[image]

Comment: It's a ngc error; not sure about disabling tho'...

Comment: Did you expert it inside the module deceleration file ?

Comment: @HaddarMacdasi  I don't want it referenced/used anywhere in my code yet. So, no.

Comment: Is it imported inside a module ?

Comment: @HaddarMacdasi  I don't want it referenced/used anywhere in my code yet. So, no.

Answer (score 0):

Having the precise same issue - and yes, it's the AoT compiler

Super frustrating